# Java + MongoDB : Group by name and count values of two different columns based on certain criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I am trying to get the desired results on Java platform.
To start with, MongoDB's aggregation framework is pretty new to me. So if the question seems trivial, kindly pardon. But I have tried to search for something similar but to no avail.

The original document structure is like this :

```
{
  "name" : "WS1",
  "previousCount" : 80,
  "currentCount" : 70
},
    {
  "name" : "WS2",
  "previousCount" : 42,
  "currentCount" : 10
},
    {
  "name" : "WS2",
  "previousCount" : 60,
  "currentCount" : 40
},
    {
  "name" : "WS1",
  "previousCount" : 60,
  "currentCount" : 20
},
    {
  "name" : "WS3",
  "previousCount" : 50,
  "currentCount" : 10
},
    {
  "name" : "WS3",
  "previousCount" : 30,
  "currentCount" : 70
},
    {
  "name" : "WS1",
  "previousCount" : 30,
  "currentCount" : 30
},
    {
  "name" : "WS1",
  "previousCount" : 80,
  "currentCount" : 50
},
```

I have to first group by the documents based on the name, and then apply a filter on the previousCount and currentCount fields and count the number of occurences for which the conditions satisfy.

So if I want to have distinct records which signify the number of times previousCount was **>=40** and **<=70** and currentCount was **>=10** and **<=50**, I should get something like this:

Thus I would finally want results like :

```
{
  "name" : "WS1",
  "qualifiedPreviousCount" : 2,
  "qualifiedCurrentCount" : 3
},
    {
  "name" : "WS2",
  "qualifiedPreviousCount" : 2,
  "qualifiedCurrentCount" : 2
},
    {
  "name" : "WS3",
  "qualifiedPreviousCount" : 1,
  "qualifiedCurrentCount" : 1
},
```

How should I proceed? MongoDB's aggregation framework is something I am finding hard to understand and apply. Help will be much appreciated as I am stuck here for long. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First of all, Have you checked out this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#examples?

Secondly, if you are or intend to use Spring Framework - then I suggest you take a look at this guide by mkyong: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-grouping-example/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't intend to use Spring and the manual you have linked to has given examples for counting one field, and it is the simultaneous counting of two fields which is causing me problems. Sorry if I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

`$group` by `name` and `$sum` with `$cond` with conditions, when match set 1 else set 0.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "qualifiedPreviousCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$previousCount",
                  40
                ]
              },
              {
                "$lte": [
                  "$previousCount",
                  70
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    "qualifiedCurrentCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$currentCount",
                  10
                ]
              },
              {
                "$lte": [
                  "$currentCount",
                  50
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Java code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");
Bson aggregates = Aggregates.group("$name",
                Arrays.asList(Accumulators.sum("qualifiedPreviousCount", new Document("$cond", Arrays.<Object>asList(new Document("$and", Arrays.<Object>asList(
                        new Document("$gte", Arrays.<Object>asList("$previousCount", 40)), new Document("$gte", Arrays.<Object>asList("$previousCount", 70))
                )), 1, 0))), Accumulators.sum("qualifiedCurrentCount", new Document("$cond", Arrays.<Object>asList(new Document("$and", Arrays.<Object>asList(
                        new Document("$gte", Arrays.<Object>asList("$currentCount", 10)), new Document("$gte", Arrays.<Object>asList("$currentCount", 50))
                )), 1, 0)))));

List<Document> results = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(aggregates)).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. The solution looks good. If you can help me out a bit more and write a java equivalent, it will be awesome. Because that's where I am mainly stuck, on restructuring this for Java.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. In the last line though, there seems to be an issue. It says - cannot resolve method 'aggregate(java.util.List<T>)'

Comment: Np. What is your java driver version ? I suspect it is 2.x version or you are using the old api in the new driver(3.x). If its later you have to get the collection using `MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");`

Comment: You were right. I was actually using old api in the new driver. The program runs smooth now. But I am only getting one document in the form of : {'name' : xx, 'qualifiedPreviousCount' : xx, 'qualifiedCurrentCount'} and not all the grouped by ones as I would expect.

Comment: I'm guessing it should `$name`

Comment: Ah right. I was just going to comment that. Thanks a lot. It works now :)